# How can I style this Facebook sign in component?

Tags: css, reactjs, function, components

I'm new to react and I have the function component which is a Facebook sign in button but I don't know how to style it,is there a way to style a signin button by facebook or google?

here is the code for (facebooklogin.js):

```
import React from "react";
import {LoginSocialFacebook} from "reactjs-social-login";
import {FacebookLoginButton} from "react-social-login-buttons";
import  {useState} from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";




function FacebookLogin()   {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
    return(
        <div>
        {!profile ? <LoginSocialFacebook
      appId="922883705581488"
      onResolve={(response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setProfile(response.data);
      }}
      onReject={(error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }}
      >
        <FacebookLoginButton />
      </LoginSocialFacebook>: ''}
  
      {profile ? <div>
        <h1>{profile.name}</h1>
        <img src={profile.picture.data.url} />
        
         </div>: ''}
      </div>
  

   
    );
}
export default FacebookLogin
```

the code for (App.js):

```
import FacebookLogin from "./Components/facebooklogin";
import GoogleLogin from "./Components/GoogleLogin";
import { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import './App.css';

class App extends Component { 
    render(){ 
 return (
    <div className="App">

     
   <FacebookLogin></FacebookLogin>

  
   

   
   </div>
 );
}
}

export default App;
```

I tried style it through a class name but did not work

Answer (score 1):

I tried this library. I found 3 approaches.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { FacebookLoginButton, createButton } from "react-social-login-buttons";

const CustomFacebookLoginButton = createButton({
  text: "Log in with Facebook 2",
  icon: "clock",
  iconFormat: name => `fa fa-${name}`, // for this icon you should include the font-awesome icon package 
  style: {
    background: "green"
  }
});

function App() {
  // The styling on the FacebookLoginButton is set on the element's style attribute.
  // I found 3 approaches to override this.
  return (<div>
      option 1: Use a custom component. see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-social-login-buttons#create-your-own-button
      <CustomFacebookLoginButton /> 
      option 2: Use style attribute.
      <FacebookLoginButton style={{ background: "red" }} />
      option 3: Use a class with `!important` styling rules. 
      <FacebookLoginButton className="_withCustomClass" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
._withCustomClass {
  background: yellow !important;
  /* important is needed to override element level styling */
}
```

I've also added the code here: [https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-social-login-buttons-by-michalszorad-forked-x9iqme)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-social-login-buttons) for the buttons.

According to the docs, you can create your own button component and apply your styles. For example, to recreate a `<FacebookLoginButton/>` you can do:

```js
// components/CustomFacebookLoginButton.jsx
import React from "react";
import {createButton} from "react-social-login-buttons";

const config = {
  text: "Log in with Facebook",
  icon: "facebook",
  iconFormat: name => `fa fa-${name}`, // if you are using font-awesome
  style: { background: "#3b5998" },
  activeStyle: { background: "#293e69" }
};

const CustomFacebookLoginButton = createButton(config);

export default CustomFacebookLoginButton ;
```

Then simply use it as:

```js
import CustomFacebookLoginButton from '../components/CustomFacebookLoginButton.jsx';

<LoginSocialFacebook ... >
  <CustomFacebookLoginButton />
</LoginSocialFacebook>
```